# Find starting offset of a partition

Tags: c++, winapi

Suppose I have a usb drive with two partition e:, f:. How do I know from which offset the partition e: or f: starts so that I can write raw data starting from that offset. I could not find any function that would provide me the offset in c++. In Dos I could easily get this with `wmic partition get Index, Name, StartingOffset`.

Comment: You can [interrogate WMI in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/creating-a-wmi-application-using-c-)

Comment: is there any other way without going to WMI

Comment: [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_drive_layout_ex) could get the [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-partition_information_ex) arrays for each partition on the drive which contains `StartingOffset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `StartingOffset` of partitions in a Physical Drive(such as `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1`), you could use [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_drive_layout_ex) to get [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-partition_information_ex) arrays for each partition:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{

    HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;                 // results flag
    DWORD junk = 0;                     // discard results
    DWORD error;

    DWORD szNewLayout = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX) * 4 * 25;
    
    
    hDevice = CreateFileW(wszDrive,          // drive to open
        GENERIC_READ,                // no access to the drive
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,             // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
        0,                // file attributes
        0);            // do not copy file attributes
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("CreateFileW error: %d\n", error);
        return -1;
    }

    DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX* pdg = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX*)malloc(szNewLayout);
    if (pdg == NULL)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("malloc error: %d\n", error);
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return -1;
    }
    ZeroMemory(pdg, szNewLayout);

    bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,                       // device to be queried
        IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, // operation to perform
        NULL, 0,                       // no input buffer
        pdg, szNewLayout,// sizeof(*pdg)*2,            // output buffer
        &junk,                         // # bytes returned
        (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);          // synchronous I/O
    if (!bResult)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("DeviceIoControl error: %d\n", error);
        free(pdg);
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pdg->PartitionCount; i++) {
        printf("partition %d: %lld\n", i, pdg->PartitionEntry[i].StartingOffset.QuadPart);
    }

    free(pdg);
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return 0;
}
```

To get the `StartingOffset` of a specified partition(such as `\\\\.\\E:`), you could use [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_partition_info_ex):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\E:"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;                 // results flag
    DWORD junk = 0;                     // discard results
    DWORD error;

    PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX piex;
    ZeroMemory(&piex, sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX));
    hDevice = CreateFileW(wszDrive,          // drive to open
        GENERIC_READ,                // no access to the drive
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,             // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
        0,                // file attributes
        0);            // do not copy file attributes
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("CreateFileW error: %d\n", error);
        return -1;
    }

    bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
        IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX,
        NULL, 0,
        &piex, sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX),
        &junk,                         
        (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
    if (!bResult)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("DeviceIoControl error: %d\n", error);
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return -1;
    }
    wprintf(L"%s StartingOffset: %lld\n", wszDrive, piex.StartingOffset.QuadPart);

    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return 0;
}
```